# Retrieve the values between two dates stored in dd/mm/yyy format (varchar)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have one table like this:

```
   +-----+------------+
   | no  | Date       |
   +-----+------------+
   | 1   | 10/11/2011 |
   | 2   | 10/12/2011 |
   | 3   | 10/13/2011 |
   | 4   | 10/14/2011 |
   | 5   | 10/15/2011 |
   +-----+------------+
```

I have written the following query, but it returns nothing because `date` is stored in a `varchar` column, in format dd/mm/yyyy.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tablname 
WHERE  date BETWEEN '10/11/2011' AND '10/15/2011'
```

**How can I find the values between two dates if my date is stored in dd/mm/yyy format?**

Please, can any one help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Is the column type varchar or DATE?

Comment: best to use timestamp `time()` subtract the two and convert to Human readable date/time.

Answer (score 6):

If you really must keep the data as a varchar, then you don't have to pull it into PHP first. You can use MySQL's Date Time functions for this

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(YourDateColumn,'%d/%m/%Y') AS RealDateColumn 
FROM YourTable
```

Or perhaps

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(YourDateColumn,'%d/%m/%Y')  < '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know about that function. Learn something new every day!

Comment: Don't forget to "Accept" whichever answer you think actually answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're storing your dates in a VARCHAR and not in one of MySQL's DATE column types then you'll need to use MySQL's STR_TO_DATE function (see Cylindric's answer).

Of course, much better would be to change the column type to a [DATE or DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html) type. To do this, you're best creating a new column with the new type, converting the data in the existing column from a string to a date, dropping the existing column and renaming the new column to the name of the old column.

Comment: You don't have to do it all in PHP. Just convert to DATETIME in MySQL. What you're suggesting would require all data to be sent to the page on every request.

Comment: @JNK Didn't know about STR_TO_DATE function, have upvoted Cylindric's answer. But the second part still stands. The OP should convert the column type to one of MySQL's native DATETIME types.

Comment: @liquorvicar I agree on using appropriate datatypes, but I'm concerned that you would think it's a good idea to pass all the data out to an application layer for conversion.

Comment: @JNK I didn't think it was a good idea. I just didn't realise you could do it in MySQL. I'm so use to using the native DATETIME types I'd never really thought string manipulation of dates was possible (but still isn't a good idea!)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with storing dates as varchars, including: it takes more space, you can enter non-date values, and the string doesn't compare correctly.

So, the short answer is: DON'T STORE DATES AS STRINGS!

The slightly longer answer is to convert the varchar to a DATE type, then compare on that.  Since the conversion isn't exactly the most efficient thing in the world, only do it once and store it.  Either just add a new column and convert the original date values (which is what I'd do), or choose one of the methods of modifying the table to change the type of the current date column (which is probably the more "correct" method, but it's a bit more work and depending on how you're currently using the data, could potentially break things).

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers have indicated it's best to store dates as date types.  There are some use cases where storing dates as strings might make sense.  In which case you should store your dates as YYYYMMDD which in turn will allow between to work as expected along with sorting.

Having said that, you could accomplish your goal with the substring/concat functions.  Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tablname WHERE
CONCAT(substring(`date`,7,4),substring(`date`,1,2),substring(`date`,3,2)) 
BETWEEN
CONCAT(substring('10/11/2011',7,4),substring('10/11/2011',1,2),substring('10/11/2011',3,2)) AND
CONCAT(substring('10/11/2011',7,4),substring('10/11/2011',1,2),substring('10/11/2011',3,2));
```

I trust that it is fairly obvious why this approach is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I am sorry, this query did not work.
Can you please send me exact query according to my requirement? or any simple query for that purpose?

Comment: I added some back ticks around date since it's a reserved word.  But you really need to take the time and learn a bit more about sql.